# Toggling @State variables using .OnTapGesture in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui, state

Can somebody tell me why this logic does not work? I am trying to create an instance of a view and store it in a variable. Then I use this variable to return a view in var body. My goal is to toggle the isActive variable of the view object on a tap so that the checkmark image is shown.

I can make this work when I put the onTapGesture inside the custom view object, but I can not get a change in state when I toggle the variable from parent view. I hope this makes sense.

```
struct SensorFamilyView: View {

    @State var analogView = FamilyItemView(title: "Analog", isActive: false)

    var body: some View {

        VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 0) {

            analogView                                   // Show view instance

                .onTapGesture {                          // I want this tap gesture to work
                    self.analogView.isActive.toggle()
            }

        }
    }
}

struct FamilyItemView: View {                            // Custom View

    @State var title: String
    @State var isActive = false

    var body: some View {


        HStack {

            if ( isActive )                              // isActive toggles a checkmark image
            {   
                Image(systemName: "checkmark.circle")
            }
            else
            {
                Image(systemName: "circle")
            }

            Text("\(title)")
        }

        .padding()
        .onTapGesture {                            // This Tap works, but not what I want
            //self.isActive.toggle()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Why won't it work?

You cannot hold an instance of `FamilyItemView`. Why? Because it is a `struct`, not a `class`. When you toggled the `isActive` property, the view is recreated (because it is using `@State`).

#### How can this be fixed?

Use `@Binding`. Creating a binding means that `FamilyItemView` will be updated when `SensorFamilyView`'s `isActive` property changes. It can be used like the following:

```
struct SensorFamilyView: View {
    
    @State private var isActive = false
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 0) {
            FamilyItemView(title: "Analog", isActive: $isActive)
                .onTapGesture {
                    self.isActive.toggle()
                }
        }
    }
}

struct FamilyItemView: View {
    
    @State var title: String
    @Binding var isActive: Bool
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            if isActive {
                Image(systemName: "checkmark.circle")
            } else {
                Image(systemName: "circle")
            }
            
            Text("\(title)")
        }.padding()
    }
}
```

<sup>Side note: As for the code right now, `title` does not need to be `@State`.</sup>

#### Additional clearing up of code

```
struct FamilyItemView: View {
    
    let title: String
    @Binding var isActive: Bool
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Image(systemName: isActive ? "checkmark.circle" : "circle")
            Text(title)
        }.padding()
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to explain this to me.

Answer (score 1):

#### @State

To understand this, we need to first touch upon `@State`. What is it?

> SwiftUI manages the storage of any property you declare as a state. When the state value changes, the view invalidates its appearance and recomputes the body.
>   ...
>   **A State instance isn’t the value itself**; it’s a means of reading and writing the value. To access a state’s underlying value, use its variable name, which returns the wrappedValue property value.
>   <sub>Ref: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/state</sub>

But why did we need `@State`? Well... Structs are value type and it's variables are non-mutating by default so to get around this, `@State` `propertyWrapper` was provided that basically wraps a value and stores and maintains it for us in some persitent<sup>*</sup> storage within the SwiftUI framework.
<sup>*See the WWDC on this for more details: https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/226/</sup>

When a `@State` property is changed within the body of the `View`'s struct in which it was declared, SwiftUI's engine automatically re-renders the body. But if it's modified from outside the view, SwiftUI does not pick up on this.

So then, now what?
That's where `@Binding` can be used to create a 2-way binding.

---

#### @Binding

> Use a binding to create a two-way connection between a property that stores data, and a view that displays and changes the data. A binding connects a property to a source of truth stored elsewhere, instead of storing data directly. For example, a button that toggles between play and pause can create a binding to a property of its parent view using the @Binding property wrapper.
>   <sub>Ref: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/binding</sub>

#### Solution:

```
struct SensorFamilyView: View {
    @State var isActive: Bool = false

    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 0) {
            FamilyItemView(title: "Title", isActive: $isActive)
                .onTapGesture {
                    self.isActive.toggle()
            }
        }
    }
}

struct FamilyItemView: View {
    @State var title: String
    @Binding var isActive: Bool

    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            if (isActive) {
                Image(systemName: "checkmark.circle")
            } else {
                Image(systemName: "circle")
            }
            Text("\(title)")
        }
    }
}
```

- `SensorFamilyView` has a state property `isActive`
- `FamilyItemView` has a binding property `isActive`

There's a 2-way binding between them so when one changes, the other also changes. Furthermore, this is all within the Combine framework (which SwiftUI is heavily based on) and so the right sequence of event are fired that cause the body to render.

Comment: Thank you very much! Extremely helpful guidance.